# How to remove or hide the legends in a Query Viewer object

Tags: genexus

I'm developing a analytics system that shows the consume from customers using an API with a lot of routes, I got almost everything, but I'm trying to remove the pie legends below the chart and I can't of no one way. So I would like to know if it's possible to remove or no, I'm using Genexus 16 for this.

That's like my chart is at the moment:
[image]

I load the chart information from the database through a query viewer on Genexus that reads a view with the information, but I don't want to keep these legends visible

I tried to search a method or property from the query viewer object that remove or hide the legend, but I didn't find anything

Like the images below:
[image]
[image]

I would like to know also about the width chart, it's a little small and I can't let it bigger